# Celebrity picture rebus

Tags: visual, knowledge, rebus

It's an easy one, lets see who gets it the fastest.[image]

**HINT:**

> He/She is a hollywood singer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pure guess.

Is it:

> Shawn Mendes?

My explanation is:

> The picture is of Shawn the Sheep. There is Man=Men and D's in the picture=Des .

Comment: This took longer than expected.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Two years longer :D

Answer (score 1):

It might be:

> Lameboy DS
> Lameboy DS is an emulator for the Nintendo DS console

Explanation:

> Lamb, the animals in the picture
> Boy the boy in the picture
> Multiple D = DS
> Combine Lamb + Boy = Lameboy
> With DS it gives Lameboy DS

Comment: Although it's not the answer, please provide an explanation everytime you post an answer

Comment: Is an emulator a celebrity?

Comment: @yass added a hint, try it now.

Answer (score 1):

> Ed Sheeran.

There’s a

> Ginger Man Shaving Shaving Sheep.